# Wrong projectKey with Jenkins Build on Sonar Analysis

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm having some trouble and I'm trying to fix my Jenkins builds.

I use it to build the same project but different branches. So, to separate the result for the Sonar analysis.

In the Build tab from my project, the options I set are : `clean install -DtestFailureIgnore sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=MY_PROJECT_KEY`

For some builds, it just works perfectly fine, and for some others, my project key in Sonar become `groupId:artifactId` using the `pom.xml` data, and it makes Sonar mixing some of the branches.

Does anyone know how to help about that problem?

Sonar version: `5.4`

Jenkins version: `1.651.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. When analysing Maven projects with the *SonarQube Scanner for Maven*, `sonar.projectKey` is automatically set to `<groupId>:<artifactId>`.

To analyse different branches of the same project: do not override `sonar.projectKey` , simply use the `sonar.branch` parameter.

Full details in the [SonarQube Analysis Parameters documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters).